# Black screen after wake up from suspend mode

Tags: release-loki, nvidia, graphics

I'm using the latest Nvidia graphics drivers. They're working very well, but sometimes when my desktop wakes up from suspend, I get a black screen, before and/or after I log in. The screen will light up and stay black. Sometimes the issue is resolved by pressing the power button on the monitor to restart it. If it doesn't work, I have to press F1 and restart lightdm the fix it. It's very annoying and I would really like to be able to fix it. I'm currently using elementary os 0.4.1 and I have a GTX 760 (OEM). With black screen I actually mean it looks like the screen fades out, it also happens sometimes when I close a fullscreen application.

Edit: I'm sorry for the late response. In my case this was related to a problem with the monitor. When I replaced it the problem was solved. It's worth considering your monitor might be bad.

Comment: (since i can't comment I'll ask in the form of an answer, then update accordingly) Is it on a laptop or Desktop? (specifically it's very nice to know if it's actually an GTX 760M, with optimus, as that changes the situation slightly ) also, could you please post the output of: find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name 'nvidia*.ko*'

Comment: Here is the output: 
`/lib/modules/4.11.7-041107-generic/kernel/drivers/video/fbdev/nvidia/nvidiafb.ko`

`/lib/modules/4.11.7-041107-generic/extra/nvidia_387.ko`

`/lib/modules/4.11.7-041107-generic/extra/nvidia_387_uvm.ko`

`/lib/modules/4.11.7-041107-generic/extra/nvidia_387_drm.ko`

`/lib/modules/4.11.7-041107-generic/extra/nvidia_387_modeset.ko`

And I'm on a desktop.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem not only with elementaryOS, but with Lubuntu as well. Its a driver problem.

Do not use the `nvidia` drivers included in the AppCenter, this is a known bug that happens with the legacy drivers included in most LTS variations of Ubuntu.

To fix just update your drivers using nvidia's driver repo.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
```

[Check your Graphics cards for a compatible Driver](http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html), for example, my GPU is Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050, so it's compatible with the Latest Short Lived branch which is `nvidia-396` as the date this answer was originally written.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-XXX
```

For Elementary OS 5.0 (and other distros based on 18.04 LTS) the package name changed:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-XXX
```

Replace XXX with the version your GPU is compatible with. The latest, the better.

Restart, the problem should be fixed.

Sources:

- http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux
- https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/963148/linux/resume-from-suspend-freeze-the-system-all-the-times-840m-driver-340-370-ubuntu-/

Comment: the final command wasn't working for me, but it worked when I replaced it with `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-xxx`

Comment: Yes, AFAIK they changed to that naming convention from 18.xx onwards.

Comment: did you guys were able to solve the black screen problem?

Comment: It did not fix the black screen for me @ThiagoDias

Comment: same, I ended up switching to another distro.
I'm currently using Fedora with gnome

Answer (score 0):

I have disabled the suspend option.
Now if I leave the laptop on and don't do anything it will go to sleep after 15 min and asks for the password when woke up.
After some idle time, the display will be turned off. Which is not the same as suspend I guess.
I think suspend option in Linux systems is not the same as the sleep option in windows.
I'm using elementary OS 6.0 ODIN

Comment: Disabling suspend will prevent the laptop from going into sleep mode, which means the CPU will stop and state will be stored to RAM. This is like sleep on Windows I think.

However, there are other things that can happen:
- Display Power Management Signaling (DPMS) may decide to turn of the screen.
- The Desktop Environment may decide to lock the screen.

This is not the same as suspend, the laptop will still be running. The lock screen will just be enabled and the display will be turned off. I think this is what's still happening in your case.