# Odin - No backlight after suspend

Tags: suspend, nvidia, release-odin, amd, backlight

I am using an Lenovo Legion 5 with an AMD Ryzen 7 5800H and a NVIDIA 3060. When I suspend my laptop, either through systemctl, the wingpanel button, closing the laptop or pressing the powerbutton, it suspends. When I then resume the laptop, it has no backlight. When I connect an external monitor that runs just fine, it's just the laptop screen.

So I've tried a bunch of things and I am running out things to try:

- Switched in BIOS to discrete mode for gpu.
- Reinstalled drivers, I tried 460, 470 and 460-server ([Black screen after wake up from suspend mode](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/14211/black-screen-after-wake-up-from-suspend-mode)).
- I tried changing kernels, by default it was 5.12 and I also tried 5.14 when I read that 5.12 sometimes has issues.
- Tried various values for GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub.
- Tried messing with nvidia services for 470 (https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/fixed-suspend-resume-issues-with-the-driver-version-470/187150)
- Tried a GDM3 as a display manager.

None of these solved the issue. I really don't know what to do anymore, any and all help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it after all. Updating to kernel 5.14 broke my trackpad, whilst trying to fix that I came across this:

https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/mmptqi/lenovo_legion_5_ubuntu_2004_final_guide_dream/

Following that guide fixed all my issues.

Comment: This is a good resource for people using the same hardware 